# How to find sub-journey matches in Google Maps using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

As we know that using "Get directions" we put starting point and destination and Google Maps shows marked route. My question is if a person X travels from A to B on a route A-a-b-B, and other person Y travels only from a to b which is a sub part of A to B,then how can I match that both are traveling on same route. In other words there path is same or in some cases some part of their path is same. IMPORTANT I have to do it in ASP.NET for a web application.

Thank you